# Мудреный цикл =)

Tags: php

У меня есть цикл:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $sql2['count']; $i++) {

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".$_SESSION['username']."' ");
    while ($inv= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "

    i[$i] = new Array('".$inv['id']."','".$inv['id_img']."','".$inv['kolovo']."',0,'".$inv['title']."',0,'".$inv['about']."',0,1);

    ";

    }
    }
```

Можно ли так делать?

И еще там ошибка, new Array выводит в дубль вот так:

```
i[1]
i[1]
i[2]
i[2]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

Comment: Ты один и тот же вопрос уже задаешь в третий или четвертый раз.

Comment: -_- ответ вообще круть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ох мать моя женщина ...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inv where username='".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username'])."'");
$i = 1;
while ($inv= mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo "\ni[$i] = new " . 
      "Array('".$inv['id']."','".$inv['id_img']."','".
      $inv['kolovo']."',0,'".
      $inv['title']."',0,'".
      $inv['about']."',0,1);
   ";
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: Йеее спасибо =)

Answer (score 2):

Надеюсь я верно понял, что вывод в JS...

ИМХО:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $_SESSION['username'] );
$query = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM inv where username = '".$username."'" );

echo 'i = [ undefined ];'."\n";
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){
  echo ''.
    'i.push(['.
      ' "'.$row['id'].    '",'.
      ' "'.$row['id_img'].'",'.
      ' "'.$row['kolovo'].'", 0,'.
      ' "'.$row['title']. '", 0,'.
      ' "'.$row['about']. '", 0, 1'.
    ']);'."\n";
}
```

P.S:

1. Вам код поддерживать, поэтому длинные однострочные выражения - очень не гуд!
2. Лучше не называть переменную `i` - если это не счетчик цикла
3. ИМХО: результат mysql_query - это `$query, $sql, $query_inv`, но не `$inv`